# IntelliJ root project showing gradle dependencies from modules as not resolvable

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

This might just be an IntelliJ bug, and it doesn't keep anything from working, but it is driving me crazy. The root project in IntelliJ shows the dependencies for the submodules are not resolvable, but they are resolving just fine. Is there something I am missing in the root project's gradle file?

Note: the catalog-core, common, and dal modules have no dependencies yet, however legacy-db and mongo-db do have dependencies. So literally every single dependency from the sub-projects resolves in its own project but not in the larger root project.

**build.gradle for AdminTools**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile project( ":catalog-admin" )
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.0.1'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'AdminTools'
include 'catalog-core'
include 'catalog-admin'
include 'catalog-common'
include 'catalog-dal'
include 'catalog-dal:legacy-db'
include 'catalog-dal:mongo-db'
```

**Screenshot of Gradle Tool Window**

[image: Screenshot of Gradle Tool Window]

Comment: Any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Does reimporting the project help? Does it build from the command line Gradle?

Comment: Can you build the project from command line, using gradle?
So far, looks like you are missing `repositories` declarations.

Comment: I agree with @NikitaSkvortsov, I think you probably missed `repositories` block before `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, adding the repositories block to the main project, with all of the repositories from all of the subprojects, did the trick. Thanks!

PS - It did build from command line at the root project level, although strangely 'gradle dependencies' didn't work. You'd think the root project would simply conglomerate all the repositories from subprojects but I guess not.